# Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded when i execute daily run from my website

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I am using phpMyAdmin from a website vendor.

It seems that i can not edit php.ini settings page.
so where to set ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); ? In my Php coding page ? or any settings page ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you cannot edit php.ini configuration, then you can set following at **top of your PHP page**:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
//OR
set_time_limit(300); //If set to zero, no time limit is imposed.
```

Note: set_time_limit(): **This function has no effect when PHP is running in safe mode.**